# What causes a mismatch in a .net core nuget package that contains an abstract class requiring a dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I've setup a nuget package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/AlexaCore/) that gets created via `dotnet pack` with parameters `/p:Version=%system.build.number%` driven off a TeamCity variable.

When I reference the package in another .netcore1.0 application and create a new `AlexaIntent` Visual Studio 2017 doesn't persist the correct parameters on the `GetResponseInternal` method. It should be: `Dictionary<string, Slot>` but defaults to `GetResponseInternal(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary slots)`

[image]

If I then correct the signature Visual Studio indicates the class doesn't correctly implement the base class:

[image]

Why might this be? Is the generation step invalid or somehow missing required settings.

FYI the `Slot` class exists in another package: Alexa.Net (https://github.com/timheuer/alexa-skills-dotnet/tree/master/Alexa.NET) which should be referenced by the nuget definition in my projects csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Alexa.NET" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Core" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

If I reference the class library without nuget (ie via a project in the same solution) then the issue is not visible.

Comment: Have you added the `System.Collections` NuGet package?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried adding to both the destination application and the source project that's used to generate the nuget package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/AlexaCore/) but unfortunately still the same thing

Comment: But that's not the `System.Collections` package...

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure what you mean? The nuget package now contains a dependency reference to `System.Collections (>= 4.3.0)`.

Comment: A dependency, but the package has been installed? .net Core includes only the minimum part of the framework, basically System.dll, you need to add manually the packages you use from the framework, enter to the nuget manager, search for "System.Collections" and import that package.

Comment: Ah I see, yes I've added `System.Collections` to the destination project as a reference from nuget but still the same issue unfortunately. It builds fine, the issue lies with how visual studio validates each class

Comment: Ok, so the project builds but VS has problems. Have you cleaned the project and restarted VS? VS sometimes has problems with IntelliSense and code analysis with .net Core and usually restarting solves it

Comment: Unfortunately I've seen the same thing on various dev machines so doesn't seem to be a temporary intellisense issue - most odd!

Answer (score 0):

Since updating to the latest version of Resharper (2017.2) this issue is no longer visible. I'd suggest doing the same.